# Google Storage - CORS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I'm developing a Web App and Chrome extensions with React App (CRA) and I want users to be able to upload files to a Google Storage bucket, directly from the front-end.
The BE (backend) generates a signed URL and sends it to the front-end. Then, the front-end takes that URL and uses it to make a PUT request to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
The backend code looks like this:

```
url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=expiration_date, method='PUT', content_type=content_type, version='v4')
```

Issue:
From the localhost Webapp (localhost:3000), I keep getting CORS errors when trying to upload files. However, when I ran the same code in the Chrome extension, it succeeded.

Some more info:

- cors config on the bucket includes localhost:3000 and still fails.

> cors_config:
> - maxAgeSeconds: 3000
> method:
> - PUT
> - POST
> - GET
> - HEAD
> origin:
> - http://localhost:3000

- I tried with signed URL v2 and v4. Also, I verified that the content type is correct.
- The front-end request to the bucket includes the "Content-Type" header.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Did you read these documents: [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) and [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors)?